# dual list box disabled selection option

Tags: html, thymeleaf, bootstrap-duallistbox

I am using Bootstrap Dual Listbox that I got from [http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/](http://I%20am%20using%20Bootstrap%20Dual%20Listbox%20that%20I%20got%20from%20http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/)

I am generating list box options using Thymeleaf.i had a scenario like -- In my *Entity has BOOLEAN column name is_generated*,
If the 'is_generated=true' means that condition based options are need become disabled,That means user **not able to select the particular option** like **HTML attribute (disabled="true")**

Here is my code

```html
 <form id="chargeslistformid" method="post" action="#" 
     th:action="@{/savechargeslist}" th:object="${wrpAssignCharges}">
         
        <label>
            <select id="selectBox" multiple="multiple"
            name="selectedChargesList" class="selectpicker form-control" >
                <option  th:each="charge:${chargeslist}" 
                th:value="${charge.pkAssignId}" 
                th:text="${charge.chargeName}"
                th:selected="${previouslist.contains(charge)}"></option>
            </select>
        </label>
        
       
        
        <br/>
        <button id="chargeslistbtnid" th:type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Next</button>
    </form>
```

Please Help me out...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the th:disabled attribute to generate a disabled-attribute depending on a condition:

```
<option
  ..
  th:disabled="${ /* condition, e.g. 1 < 2 or #object.property == ... */ }"
>
</option>
```

Comment: Thanks Flocke,i will try this